# D3 - Add dots in middle of lines between two points

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am drawing lines with D3 between two points which is working fine but want to add dots / points in the middle of the lines.

I'm following [this example in the D3 docs](https://observablehq.com/@harrylove/draw-a-circle-dot-marker-on-a-line-path-with-d3) but can't get it to work with my own code.

Here's the code that draws the lines:

```js
export default function drawLines(): DrawLines {
    const getSVG = (
        ref: SVGSVGElement | null,
        viewBoxHeight: number,
    ): d3Selection | undefined => {
        if (ref) {
            const svg = d3
                .select(ref)
                .attr('viewBox', `0 0 350 ${viewBoxHeight}`);
            return svg;
        }
        return undefined;
    };

    const getLine = (idx: number, arr: Array<NodePositions>): d3Line => {
        const line = d3
            .line<Number>()
            .x((value, index) => arr[idx].x[index])
            .y((value) => Number(value));
        return line;
    };

    const drawLine = (nodes: Array<NodePositions> | undefined, svg: d3Selection): void => {
        if (nodes) {
            nodes.forEach((el, idx, arr) => {
                if (svg) {
                    svg
                        .selectAll(null)
                        .data([el.y])
                        .join('path')
                        .attr('d', (value: Number[] | Iterable<Number>) => getLine(idx, arr)(value));
                }
            });
        }
    };

    return { getSVG, drawLine };
}
```

How can I add points / dots or shapes in the middle of the lines?

Comment: What's your data format? `[{x: number, y: number}, ...]` or something else?

Comment: Hi @MichaelRovinsky, it's `[{x: [number, number], y: [number, number]}]` where each number in the array refers to the first and second point respectively (start and end of line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
svg.selectAll('circle')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', d => (d.x[0] + d.x[1]) / 2)
  .attr('cy', d => (d.y[0] + d.y[1]) / 2)
  .attr('r', 3)
  .style('fill', 'red');
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael - unfortunately it's not working - I get `attr.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: this.setAttribute is not a function` when I try to use the `.enter()` method

Comment: @Mr.Robot Hi, and sorry for the error - I just fixed it in the answer. Please check it out again.